# how to access prom lib.rs from main.rs of pilot

Tags: rust, module, rust-crates

I have a project that have peach  (library)  and pilot (binary) directories

**directory structure**

```
peach / src / lib.rs
peach / prom / src / lib.rs
pilot / src / main.rs
```

**main.rs of pilot-**

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    add(3,6);
}
```

**lib.rs of prom -**

```
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) {
    let sum = a + b;

    println!("Sum of a and b = {}", sum);
}
```

how to access prom lib.rs from main.rs of pilot

**my main cargo.toml is -**

```
[workspace]
members = ["pilot", "peach"]
```

**pilot cargo.toml -**

```
[package]
name = "pilot"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
[dependencies.peach]
path = "../peach"
```

**peach cargo.toml -**

```
[package]
name = "peach"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
[dependencies.prom]
path = "./prom"
```

**prom cargo.toml -**

```
[package]
name = "prom"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

Comment: What about just `use peach::add;`?

Comment: May I know why have you structured your project in this way specifically the prom inside peach?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman , it is giving error - error[E0432]: unresolved import `peach::add`

Comment: @ShindeArjun no specific reason, exploring crate and module

Answer (score 0):

when I add this code in **pilot cargo.toml** -

```
dependencies.prom]
path = "../peach/prom"
```

and add this code to main.rs

`use prom::add;`

Comment: but then again I'm not actually accessing prom from peach and from pilot , pilot can access prom because there is a dependency in its cargo.toml